# Wrap generated tags on separated divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this markup generated and I can´t modify it:

```
<h2>Title</h2>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<h3>Title</h3>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
<h3>Title</h3>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
```

What I want is to wrap it like this using jQuery:

```
<div class="article">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
</div>
<div class="article">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
</div>
<div class="article">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Any ideas how do to do it? As you can see the number of `p` tags vary so I don´t know how to target this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use can use

- [header-selector](http://api.jquery.com/header-selector/) - to select the header elements
- [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) - to select all the other sibling elements under the article
- [addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) - add the header element back to the element set
- [wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) - wrap all elements with the div

Try

```
$(':header').each(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil(':header').addBack().wrapAll('<div class="article" />')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Z9k2D/)

---

A slightly better performing version can be(since it can make use of css selectors)

```
$('h2, h3').each(function () {
    $(this).nextUntil('h2, h3').addBack().wrapAll('<div class="article" />')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7QjXj/)